# Symbol for "not absolutely continuous" in Latex

Tags: symbols

I have trouble finding the symbol which indicates that two measure are not absolutely continuous i.e. the negation of $\mu \ll \nu$. Anyone has an idea how to write this?

Edit 1:

[image]

Comment: Can you add an image?

Comment: Just added one, sorry for my drawing skills.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The `\centernot` package is made for that:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,centernot}

\newcommand{\nll}{\centernot{\ll}}

\begin{document}

$a\ll b$

$a\nll b$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 12):

`txfonts` has `\nll`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{txfonts}

\begin{document}

\[
\nll
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

`MnSymbol` also has this letter:

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{MnSymbol}

\begin{document}

\[
\nll
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice findings :-) However the `txfonts` package is deprecated for a while now. You should replace that with `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` for text and math fonts, respectively.

Answer (score 12):

In the modern toolchain, `\not\ll` appears to work fine with most Unicode math fonts.  You can declare `\newcommand\nll{\mathrel{\not\ll}}` if you prefer.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}
\( \not\ll \)
\end{document}
```

[image: Latin Modern Math sample]

As always with `unicode-math`, compile with LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX.

Answer (score 10):

You can build the symbol by superimposing the `\ll` with a `/`:

> [image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\nll}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\@nll{}}}
\def\@nll#1#2{\m@th\ooalign{\hfil$#1\ll$\hfil\cr\hfil$#1/$\hfil\cr}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\(\mu\nll\nu\)

\(a^{\mu\nll\nu}\)

\(a^{b^{\mu\nll\nu}}\)
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

A simple solution for the default font:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\nll}{\mathrel{\not{\mkern -7mu\ll}}}

\begin{document}

$ \mu\nll \nu $

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Edit by comment: using a macro `\notll` to obtain your symbol.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\newcommand{\notll}{\makebox[0pt][l]{$\mkern10mu/$}\ll}
\begin{document}
$a\notll b$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Probably better to call your symbol `\notll`, since `\negll` suggest `\neg`, which is the ¬ symbol. (OMG! I actually used that thing on my keyboard for probably the first time in thirty years of using PCs! Thank you, Sebastiano!)

Comment: @DavidRicherby Approved! Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Using the most basic, standard tool, namely the `\not` operator which can negate any operator by crossing it with a slash.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
$\mu \not\ll \nu$.

$a \not < b$.

$x\not \ge y$. 
\end{document}
```

[image]