# How to type "not absolutely continuous" with unicode-math?

Tags: math-mode, unicode-math

I've tried both `\nu\not\ll\mu` and `\nu\centernot\ll\nu`. I'm including `amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, centernot, mathtools, thmtools, unicode-math` and compiling with XeLaTeX. This is the ouput:

[image]

I suppose `unicode-math` is causing the error. How can I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/497053/134574 (there's an `unicode-math` solution there).

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik As far as I can see the suggested solution is to write `\mathrel{\not\ll}` (what's `\mathrel` doing here?). Unfortunately, the output is still the same.

Comment: The 6 looks as if your system is outdated. In an older version there was a bug leading this this, see https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/363.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I'm compiling on overleaf.

Comment: overleaf has outdated files.

Comment: Although you should prabably not use Overleaf, in my system (up-to-date TL'19) the output with XeTeX looks weird with both egreg's `\centernot` and Davislor's `unicode-math` solution. It works with my `\ooalign` solution though (not an advertisement :-). I have no idea why though...

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik as mentioned in the bug report, xelatex is missing an option to get the placement right "automatically". So fine-tuning it manually as you do with the \ooalign solution is the best solution.